# Responsive design vs adaptive design

Tags: responsive-design, adaptive-design

Would you explain difference between RWD (Responsive Web Design) and AWD (Adaptive Web Design) in a simple way?

Comment: did you google? http://bloggingexperiment.com/archives/responsive-web-design-rwd-vs-adaptive-web-design-awd.php

Comment: google 2: [responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design](http://www.junowebdesign.com/responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adaptive (AWD): Not necessarily set on a fluid grid; targets specific device resolutions (320, 768, 1024, et.al.); can have set widths (fixed) or relative widths (%), controlled by media queries.

Responsive (RWD): Built on a fluid grid; will change with the browser, no matter what the screen resolution; content can break apart and realign if need be.

In short: RWD is like AWD, except taken a step or two further, in order to future proof design for unknown devices as well as known devices.

Comment: +1: I'll add these resources to the conversation. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/adaptive-fluid-approach-responsive-web-design/ and http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-foundation-for-the-web/ (see my pyramid under Strategy)

Comment: So AWD may not mind about resolutions between those breakpoints (320,768, ...) but RWD cares about it. Is it right?

Comment: Adaptive relies on Client or server side code, so if you want to care about it you could make that happen via Javascript, etc.  One usecase to keep in mind is using both. Create one responsive CSS for mobile & one for PCs. Then use some Adaptive Techniques to filter out the clients device & load in the appropriate responsive styles. In this scenario you get the best of both worlds. You could stay responsive across mobile devices, however you won't end up with a web view if someone is using a larger resolution mobile device, and also have the option to keep a fixed or fluid design on the web.

Comment: I disagree with this characterization of AWD: Wikipedia has it right in my view: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_web_design

Comment: What was the basis to assign the words Responsive and Adaptive to resolution independence and resolution dependence respectively? It is an absurd use of terminology. I don't see any adaptability in any of these descriptions. How can a site adapt without storing history? Does anyone in the web design field even know what adaptability is?

Comment: @FauChristian: The site adapts to it's environment, taking advantage of opportunities provided. In my book, incidentally titled Adaptive Web Design, I discuss this in detail. In the first edition, I also discuss the parallels between this approach and evolutionary adaptations. And, for what it's worth, you can store history on the server or the client to have session based or perpetual adaptation, depending on how fancy you wanna get.

Comment: @AaronGustafson, using the term Adaptive to simply disginguish size units, the multiplicative factor in the layout container algorithms, grossly diminishes its meaning of the term. It's like calling a spreadsheet adaptive because it specifies macroeconomic projections as % of GNP instead of USD. I'm fine with the term being applied to some of the machine learning algorithms employed in web apps, but not for simple layout proportions. For CSS, regardless of the unit of specification, the browser is responding not adapting to the viewport. But you have a right to think and publish otherwise.

Comment: @fauchristian I get your characterization, but I'm thinking way beyond just CSS. The entire experience can (and should) adapt not only in terms of visual layout, but also behavior, and so on. And the browser isn't the only thing that a page can adapt to, it should also adapt to the user and their needs. Language, layout, contrast, input methods, etc. Are all ways in which a single web page can adapt to the situation and the person using it to best meet their needs. And to me responsive design (which is to say responsive layouts) is a part of that, but not the whole shebang.

Comment: @AaronGustafson, thank you for seeing the sense in my perspective, and I see the sense in today's reply. I'd be interested in reading your book (if I ever get some time this year - lol) and if I get even more time (not likely anytime soon) I'd be interested in writing another book too, on adaptive web experiences to discuss providing increasingly streamlined user interfaces that become familiar with individual visitors and adapt to them and more global user interaction patterns. Nice to meet you. :)

Comment: Not only are these descriptions inaccurate, but quite unhelpful.

Answer (score 11):

#### Fluid Lay­out

> Adjusts in a **word-wrap fash­ion** as screen width is increased or
> reduced.

### Adaptive Layout

> There are pre­de­fined sizes were dif­fer­ent lay­outs are trig­gered.
> These are called **breakpoints**. Adaptive layout can be either fluid
> or completely static!

### Responsive Layout

> **Combination** of Fluid and Adaptive Layout. Provides optimal experience.

### Progressive Enhancement

> Process of honoring your content (and your users) by applying
> technologies in an intelligent way, **layer-upon-layer**. Progressive enhancement doesn’t require that you provide the same experience in different browsers.

*Source:*
http://bloggingexperiment.com/archives/responsive-web-design-rwd-vs-adaptive-web-design-awd.php

Answer (score 8):

From [my blog post on the topic](http://blog.easy-designs.net/archives/2011/11/16/on-adaptive-vs-responsive-web-design/):

> “Responsive web design,” as coined by Ethan Marcotte, means “fluid
>   grids, fluid images/media & media queries.” “Adaptive web design,” as
>   I use it, is about creating interfaces that adapt to the user’s
>   capabilities (in terms of both form and function). To me, “adaptive
>   web design” is just another term for “progressive enhancement” of
>   which responsive web design can (an often should) be an integral part,
>   but is a more holistic approach to web design in that it also takes
>   into account varying levels of markup, CSS, JavaScript and assistive
>   technology support.
>
> For the record, I do think it’s important to draw a distinction
>   between “adaptive web design” and “adaptive layouts” because “adaptive
>   layouts” implies only the use of media queries, which may not be done
>   in a progressively enhanced way. Adaptive layouts achieved in a
>   mobile-first manner, however, are very likely progressive enhancement
>   and, thereby, a means of “adaptive web design.”

Answer (score 7):

An alternate definition that I've seen breaks it down by where the magic happens:

- **Responsive** -- *client-side* -- the same page is returned to all devices, but the display of the page responds to the devices, typically using JavaScript and CSS (especially media queries).
- **Adaptive** -- *server-side* -- information is passed to the server regarding the device's specs, and a page adapted to that device is returned. This would use some of the same JavaScript/CSS techniques as RWD, but some of the content may be different / smaller.

Source: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/garrett-goodman/adaptive-design_b_2344569.html

Not sure how this definition fits together with some of the others that talk more about the flow of the page content.

Answer (score 4):

The **difference between adaptive web design and responsive web design** is wider and more important than distinctions that have been suggested in this thread.  The difference is neither a mater of where software functionality resides nor what unit of measurement is used in CSS conditions.

Neither term (adaptive or responsive) is a brand, so we should not deviate from the basic definitions of the words.  In computer science, a response is an action, event, or message generated upon some stimulus.  This definition originated from biology.  The dilation of pupils in response to light is a responsive design.

Adaptation is denotes much higher functionality than simply a programmed response.  The ABILITY TO DEVELOP pupils that can dilate is an adaptive design.  Adaptation requires the storage of history and its later application.  In biology, the adaptation requires DNA to store adaptations.  In web design, adaptations could be stored in cookies or the user's account profile on the server.

Let's start with the simpler of the two.  A good formal definition of a responsive web design is this:

> *A **responsive web design** examines display characteristics and instantaneously respond in the display of pages in ways that go beyond the built in automatic layout capabilities of HTML to provide a convenient, functional, and maximally visible experience across varied display conditions.*

Portable devices have raised the importance of this additional size responsiveness.  Many such design techniques center around the addition of conditions to the CSS (cascading style sheet or sheets) or via scripting (such as JavaScript).  Each condition based on display characteristics improves the overall user experience by controlling the values of specific style parameters for a set of document elements (tags), identified by CSS selectors.*

Using either the dictionary definition or the common computer science definition of ADAPTIVE, the document layout of an adaptive web design must vary intelligently based on some higher criteria than a simple static size threshold, criteria that are evaluated continuously.  A good definition of an adaptive web design is this:

> *An **adaptive web design** records the patterns of usage and conditions of use and adapts, over time, to more quickly, comprehensively, or individualistically provide users with content and functionality.*

Some of the other uses of the term ADAPTIVE in regard to web design gives too much credit to what is merely another responsive design methodology, no smarter or more adaptive than any other.

Simple adaptive schemes can be programmed into JavaScript to vary CSS based on JSON data returned from RestFUL calls to the server to acquire user scroll and click stats from a database via SQL or NOSQL.  More advanced user experience analytics might use a rules based system (such as DRules or Prolog) or fuzzy logic, neural net, or Bayesian schemes that run asynchronously.

An example of a simple rule is, "Sort the links in order from the most frequently to the least frequently clicked and every 10 displays put a less popular link in second place to ensure elements can trickle up over time."

Trivial feedback forms are common feedback mechanisms.

Comment: This is the only post on this page that demonstrates any comprehension of adaptability whatsoever. @Douglas Daseeco, it is unfortunate that so many people are jumping on such a moronic band wagon.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best link to differentiate between fluid, fixed, responsive and adaptive layout.
http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-responsive-website/introduction-to-responsive-web-design/fixed-fluid-adaptive-and-responsive-2.
In simple words for the styles applied in your html page,

1. Fixed layout : Using pixels.
2. Fluid layout : Using percentage.
3. Responsive layout : Using only percentages with media queries
4. Adaptive layout : Using both pixels and percentages with media queries

Answer (score 0):

simply:

**RWD (Responsive):** is a different structure and design of the website that targets a certain device.
(mainly we are talking about a server side work because we are talking about different structure and different functionality)

**AWD (Adaptive):** is different design with the same structure that targets a certain device.
(mainly we are talking about a client side work because we are talking about different design only)

**note that the both technics aim to create a different user experience more friendly for a certain device**

Answer (score -1):

**In Sense Of website design:** 
**Responsive Design:** Web Page create with **Fluid grid** and **Flexible content** (E.g. images) and media query( in css). This will adapt the layout according to the browsers/device width.
**In Adaptive Design:** Web Page create  with  Fixed layout means neither fluid grid nor flexible contents. Break page layout with specific points(E.g. using media query).

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add value over the multiple existing answers. In the future, please take a glance at existing answers before posting one yourself, in order to avoid posting grossly redundant material.